# Is data 128 bit or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, httpcookie

I'm trying to determine if a third party website is using 128 bit cookies. Ive looked in Fiddler and can see the below entries when i sign into the site

`CookieName1=134EBA412103A4E3FAC3238AC739D4D47DA5466D6C0E047C25E7F54CBB1D96BB27950F6FC6F40B5FF97807EF5F7431508B374C803E311ED4A6D01386761939ED0B5E7FF0DAC7AF8A79000F0B15EB768F92B865699F49` - **1152 characters in total but i have shortened it for clarity**

`CookieTOKEN=Xmw6X26bHpqEGCWVoPfejqdZm113OIYi1C-hR_xB7I5AB1lu2ib_3Uzcagt4-XmUGsirxcpjgV1IHTmle7K0jyegvo_qyAxEnb01piTFHuE1`

`ABCD-V=EJZBZEx0DJKjJrjbUn2AfPloZbXSkBD3WeOKHXaiGxNOS45Ac7R9ri58R1oHx50syMLzXwuCan4Mvxh-XVmnGnBr6JXK54wz7Ysp-Xk5Acc1`

But I can't determine if these cookies are classed as 128 bit or not?

I've searched google which gives examples of counting characters but I'm still unsure

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "128 bit cookie" ?

Comment: By that i mean 128 bit encryption, but would that increase the length of characters?